# InvalidProgramException in Team Foundation Server Sample

Tags: c#, exception, tfs

Hi I get an System.InvalidProgramException while trying to run the Example Project called "C# Example.WorkItemBrowser".
The Exception also apears when I try to execute these lines:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfserver = new TeamFoundationServer("http://localhost:8085");
tfserver.EnsureAuthenticated();
WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(tfserver);
Console.WriteLine(store.Projects.Count);
```

I'm using the 2008 Visual Studio SDK for that.

PEverify for the assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll

got this otuput:

```
[MD]: Error: Value class has neither fields nor size parameter. [token:0x020000B3]
[MD]: Error: Value class has neither fields nor size parameter. [token:0x020000BF]
[MD]: Error: Value class has neither fields nor size parameter. [token:0x020000C4]
3 Error(s) Verifying Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
```

A fresh download and install of the SDK as well as deinstall and install as well as installing .net 3.5 sp1 again didn't help.

Is something wrong with the description of my problem or did it just not happen anywhere else?

Comment: This solved my problem: [TFS 2008 SDK will cause InvalidProgramException while running as 64 bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jianges/tfs-2008-sdk-will-cause-invalidprogramexception-while-running-as-64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I just a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015648/how-do-i-distribute-a-service-that-uses-the-team-foundation-server-api).

Turns out, you have to have Team Explorer installed on the machine you are executing this code on.