# How do I distribute a service that uses the Team Foundation Server API?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

There are tons of great examples of creating work items using the TFS API, which is all packaged as part of the VS 2008 SDK.  So, imagine I've created a simple web service that takes a few bits of information, then creates a work item.

Everything works wonderfully locally, but what if I want to deploy that web service somewhere else?  Locally, I just reference:

1)  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
2)  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

Has anyone had any luck figuring out how to deploy a library or service using these libraries on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio or the VS SDK installed on it?  Is there some sort of TFS SDK redistributable available?  Probably some licensing reason for this?

BTW, if I just copy those dlls out to the web server, I get the following error:

System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

Ick.

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:*  something of note, [this person had the exact same problem](http://forums.asp.net/p/1270758/2401344.aspx), no resolution...

*EDIT:*  sigh.  googled/hacked for three hours, then posted this, then five minutes later found what I think is the answer.  [Must install Team Explorer?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/651f1ca7-45fa-443f-835c-a6b331f99e43)  Verifiable?

***FINAL EDIT:*  Yep, that's it.  Install Team Explorer and away it goes...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think there is a TFS redistributable.  You can download and install the [explorer client](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86), but you still need to have a license (CAL) associated with that installation.

**EDIT: THIS IS NO LONGER CORRECT (2014).** As the answer from @LordHits suggests, Microsoft now provides a redistributable for this, clearly labled 'Free'.

Comment: looks like you get dibs on the 5 points ;-)  +1 for help noting the CAL though...

Answer (score 1):

The following 2 links can be considered "redistributables" for TFS:

[For TFS 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75)

[For TFS 2012 Update 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa)

Comment: If the link is broken try googling ' ''Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 4 Object Model Installer - Free - This is the stand-alone Object Model Installer for TFS 2012 (Update 4). This may be used for developing applications that integrate with TFS 2012.

Comment: FYI: I tried using this for a TFS 2010 web service that I installed on a fresh server where I was receiving errors that it couldn't find various libraries.  After installing this package, it changed which libraries were causing the problem and I could not fix it.  I had to break down and install Team Explorer to make it work