# What do I need to install on a computer to use the TFS Object Model?

Tags: tfs

I have written an application that uses the TFS Object Model to interact with TFS. What do I need to install on the client computer that's needed for my application to run?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: Duplicate: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043684/deployment-of-code-which-uses-the-microsoft-team-foundation-server-apis

Comment: Thanks ;) I haven't noticed that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this question answered:

[Deployment of code which uses the Microsoft Team Foundation Server APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043684/deployment-of-code-which-uses-the-microsoft-team-foundation-server-apis)